# How do I install Blenrig Addon in blender 2.9

Tags: python

I am using blender 2.9 and I want to install Blenrig for my character but there are many python files in the folder and I am unable to find the option "Install from Folder". How do I install the addon?

Comment: Just a **WARNING**: **BlenRig** does **NOT work** in **Blender 2.83 to 2.9x**. You will end up with severe issues after you had to run the fix buttons ("Fix Joints") and ("Calc Rolls") https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/188167/issue-with-execution-of-calc-rolls-function. It works fine with the old Blender **2.82a** version.

Answer (score 1):

From [BlenRig 5 Documention](https://cloud.blender.org/p/blenrig/5cb14ebd808c0e07cdde1d03)

> Download the BlenRig .zip file.
>
> Blender allows to install .zip addons easily. Open User Preferences,
> go to the Add-on tab, and press "Install From File". Then browse to
> the download directory where the zip is.

After this is done, the add-on should appear in preferences available for use.

[image]

---

A new rig is added via <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>*>Armature>Blenrig 5 Biped Rig*

Also, from the docs:

> You will find the rig in the Object Add Panel, under the Armature
> Menu. In the View3d Sidebar you will find all the animation controls.
> In the Armature Data Panel you will find all the rigging related
> tools.